# Screen parameters not optimal on Linux/Debian with the hyper-V on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, debian, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am trying to set up the screen resolution on Debian guest with the Hyper-V on Windows 10. Actually I'm able to login into Gnome,but the screen is larger than the screen and it flickers. The Debian guest is installed physically on the disk 0,partition 2 and it is already able to boot on the hyper-v. The debian's kernel version is :

```
4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2-bpo8+1 (2017-06-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the xorg.conf file that I'm using :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "Layout0"
    Screen 0 "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice "Mouse0" "CorePointer" 
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol"  "auto"
    Option      "Device"    "/dev/psaux"
    Option      "Emulate3Buttons"   "no"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor0"
    VendorName  "Unknown"
    ModelName   "Unknown"
    HorizSync   28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh 43.0 - 72.0
    Option      "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    #VendorName "Nvidia"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Screen0"
    Device      "Device0"   
    Monitor     "Monitor0"

    # This section was added, to prevent the screen
    # to switch to 1600x1200.
    #
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 16
        Modes   "1280x800" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have also tried to add in the file `"/etc/default/grub"` the argument:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1366x768"
```

but these solution don't work for me. They don't fix the problems I have,that are the following :

1. the virtual machine window where is contained Debian is larger than
   the x axis of the screen (I have two monitors configured at 1920 x 1080)
2. the screen inside the virtual machine is flickering
3. the graphic quality is low

The host machine is configured like this :

1. running Windows 10 pro
2. Processor : Intel Core I5-4670K CPU 3.40Ghz
3. Installed memory (RAM) : 8 GB (7.89 GB usable)
4. System type : 64 OS,X64 based processor
5. Graphic cards are : nvidia geforce GTX 660 and Intel HD Graphics 4600

If you need to have furter informations,please ask me. At the moment I don't know what could I tell you more than this. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that if I modify the file "/etc/default/grub" by adding the argument:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1366x768"

it does not stick,but if I add the line "video=hyperv_fb:1366x768" to the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg to each kernel version of debian,it works...

Comment: And it seems that the content of xorg.conf is not considered at all.